# Fedora 25 workstation does not default to wayland using nouveau on nvidea card with gnome

Tags: fedora, x11, upgrade, gnome3, wayland

After upgrading both a desktop and laptop from Fedora 24 to fedora 25 I had verified that wayland could be set and tested some development code on it.

Developer apps and debug repositories were added over time.

After the numerous updates that occur when a new version is released I was testing some development code and noticed that the Xserver was being used
and tried logging out of the desktop to gdm login screen and set wayland
which fails to start.

The `ps axf` command on the desktop now shows

```
 979 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm
 1272 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
 1294 tty1     Ssl+   0:00  |   \_ /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart --debug
 1296 tty1     Sl+    0:01  |       \_ /usr/libexec/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/42/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -backgr
 1305 tty1     Sl+    0:00  |       \_ /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart --debug
 1325 tty1     Sl+    0:02  |           \_ /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 1423 tty1     Sl     0:00  |           |   \_ ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
 1427 tty1     Sl     0:00  |           |       \_ /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
 1503 tty1     Sl     0:00  |           |       \_ /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simple
 1452 tty1     Sl+    0:00  |           \_ /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
 1546 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
 1572 tty2     Ssl+   0:00      \_ /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session --run-script gnome-session
 1578 tty2     Sl+    0:21          \_ /usr/libexec/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -back
 1595 tty2     Sl+    0:00          \_ /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary
 1672 tty2     Sl+    0:18              \_ /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

Verifying that even gdm has defaulted to X. Which in Fedora 24 was using wayland.

Not sure what changed to end up with defaulting to X on two development
system computers.

No nvidea closed source drivers are in use, just the open source nouveav driver on both laptop and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out fedora 25 will not run native wayland on Nvidea hardware and defaults to X if using the standard video drivers.